# Keycloak SPI custom labels

Tags: keycloak

I'm building a Keycloak UserStorage SPI. For it, I need to configure some properties...

```
public class MyUserStorageProviderFactory implements UserStorageProviderFactory<MyUserStorageProvider> {
  //...
  @Override
  public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    if (configProperties == null) {
      configProperties = ProviderConfigurationBuilder.create().property().name(Constants.CONFIG_URL)
          .helpText(Constants.CONFIG_URL_HELP).label(Constants.CONFIG_URL_LABEL)
          .type(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE).add().property().name(Constants.CONFIG_USERNAME)
          .helpText(Constants.CONFIG_USERNAME_HELP).label(Constants.CONFIG_USERNAME_LABEL)
          .type(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE).add().property().name(Constants.CONFIG_PASSWORD)
          .helpText(Constants.CONFIG_PASSWORD_HELP).label(Constants.CONFIG_PASSWORD_LABEL)
          .type(ProviderConfigProperty.PASSWORD).secret(true).add().build();
    }
    return configProperties;
  }
```

And Constants.CONFIG_URL_LABEL as an example is just a string like "my url". Inside the Keycloak Admin, it presents these strings. My problem is - how can I use i8n labels here? The SPI is deployed as a JAR in `standalone/deployments`.

I don't want to build a custom theme for that? Adding a file `META-INF/messages/messages_en.properties` has no effect. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a custom theme. Please take a look at the [keycloak source code for `update-profile-on-first-login` help text](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f423c0dc5138fe14b985c17b46ff433da4056d25/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/broker/IdpReviewProfileAuthenticatorFactory.java#L104) and [the translation (`admin-messages_en`)](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f423c0dc5138fe14b985c17b46ff433da4056d25/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_en.properties#L615) for admin-messages.

Comment: Changing to the {{}} jinja-template style layout strings doesn't have any effect. Both ways are working (keycloak 9.0.3). The key is replaced with the message from the resource.

Adding a themes/base/messages/xyz-messages_en.properties doesn't have any effect, the same with adding it to the jar. What worked - add the keys to admin-messages_en.properties.

Also I check https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#deploying-themes - so, the theme is part of the JAR and I can select it - but - funny or not - the new resources are not visible.... that can't be true....

Comment: At this point, I recommend checking the keycloak code locally and debugging the keycloak instance. Good luck!